# Como utilizar o EventArgs dos eventos

Tags: c#, winforms

Talvez a pergunta fiquei muito abrangente, mas queria saber como utilizar o `EventArgs` de alguns componentes, como o `EventArgs` no `Button_Click`.

Explicando um pouco melhor a duvida, por exemplo. Eu estou criando uma aplicação em que utilizo `BackgroundWorker` e `Timer` (Windows.Forms.Timer). E no caso do `BackgroundWorker` quando utilizo o `RunWorkerAsync` passando um parâmetro eu consigo pegar o valor passado no parâmetro e utiliza-lo na função desde que a variável receba o `cast` apropriado. Como no código abaixo:

```
public void execBackgroundWorker()
{
    BackgroundWorker bgwMain = new BackgroundWorker();
    bgwMain.DoWork += BgwMain_DoWork;

    int iValor = 1234;

    bgwMain.RunWorkerAsync(iValor);
}

private void BgwMain_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int valorParam = (int)e.Argument;
    Console.Write(valorParam);
}
```

Mas no caso de um `Button`, o click dele não tem um `overload` no `PerformClick` que permita passar algum parâmetro, mas ainda tenho um `EventArgs` na chamada do método. Eu entendo que o `DoWorkEventArgs` herda de `CancelEventArgs` e `CancelEventArgs` herda de `EventArgs` e que a implementação acaba por permitir que o `DoWorkEventArgs` armazene os valores de variáveis como no código acima. Mas qual seria a funcionalidade do `EventArgs` em outros eventos como o `Click` do `Button`, `Tick` do `Timer`, dentre vários outros eventos que utilizam a forma genérica de `EventArgs`?

O que o `EventArgs` armazena no `Click` para que ele seja utilizado?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> O que o `EventArgs` armazena no clique para que ele seja utilizado?

No clique de um `button`? **Nada**, pelo menos não naturalmente.

Este parâmetro serve para que sejam passados argumentos (0, 1 ou mais) para o evento. Possivelmente o maior objetivo de centralizar tudo dentro do `EventArgs` é para manter sempre a mesma assinatura padrão nos métodos (`public void evento(object sender, EventArgs e`), dessa forma você consegue passar vários argumentos dentro de um argumento só (dentro do `EventArgs`).

Repare na classe [`MouseEventArgs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx), usada nos eventos `MouseUp`, `MouseDown` e `MouseMove`, ela tem as propriedades **`Button`**, **`Clicks`**, **`Delta`**, **`Location`**, **`X`** e **`Y`**. Isto é, são vários valores passados num mesmo parâmetro.

[**`EventArgs`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.eventargs(v=vs.110).aspx) é a classe base de várias outras, como a `MouseEventArgs`, citada no exemplo, ou no `BackgroundWorker` como você já notou. Assim funciona com todos os outros componentes, isso permite que você crie um `EventArgs` e passe valores definidos por você quando o evento for disparado.

Então, a resposta para a sua pergunta:

> "*Mas qual seria a funcionalidade do EventArgs em outros eventos como o Click do Button, Tick do Timer, dentre vários outros eventos que utilizam a forma genérica de EventArgs?*"

é **depende**. Você vai precisar ler a documentação da classe para entender qual o objetivo ou o que você pode fazer com ela. Com a `MouseEventArgs` é possível capturar qual o botão do *mouse* foi clicado, qual a posição **X** e **Y** do clique, quantas vezes foi clicado, entre outros.